# How to import all submodules?

Tags: python, import, module

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
| main.py
| scripts
|--| __init__.py
   | script1.py
   | script2.py
   | script3.py
```

In `main.py`, if I `import scripts`, this apparently does not allow me to use `scripts.script1`. I know I can use `from scripts import *` to access the modules in the `scripts` package, but then I can only use them directly as `scripts1`, `scripts2` etc.

How can I write the code so that I can refer to `scripts.script1` inside `main.py`?

I tried using `pkgutils.walk_packages`, as well as the `__all__` attribute of the package, to get the submodule names, but I couldn't figure out a way to use those strings to do the import.

Comment: will pkgutil work if you deploy the application as a zipped egg? you can have a look at "import pkg_resources", just in case

Comment: I am very confused by this questions and the answers. Why this is needed at all. It's my understanding that you have two options to include all your local "modules" in python (what other languages just refer to as files. a) you include a blank init file in every folder and that ALONE tells python that this is a modules folder and to import it all before running or b) to avoid having init files everywhere, you put a preamble at the top of your files to add everything to the path. There are other considerations, like code navigation in IDEs.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Edit:** Here's one way to recursively import everything at runtime...

(Contents of `__init__.py` in top package directory)

```
import pkgutil

__all__ = []
for loader, module_name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
    __all__.append(module_name)
    _module = loader.find_module(module_name).load_module(module_name)
    globals()[module_name] = _module
```

I'm not using `__import__(__path__+'.'+module_name)` here, as it's difficult to properly recursively import packages using it.  If you don't have nested sub-packages, and wanted to avoid using `globals()[module_name]`, though, it's one way to do it.

There's probably a better way, but this is the best I can do, anyway.

**Original Answer** (For context, ignore othwerwise. I misunderstood the question initially):

What does your `scripts/__init__.py` look like?  It should be something like:

```
import script1
import script2
import script3
__all__ = ['script1', 'script2', 'script3']
```

You could even do without defining `__all__`, but things (pydoc, if nothing else) will work more cleanly if you define it, even if it's just a list of what you imported.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining fully. I have edited the main post. I am looking to import the submodules dynamically at run-time.

Comment: @linkmaster03 - Sorry for the misunderstanding.  See the changes above... It's ugly, but it works.  There's probably a better way, though.

Comment: Thanks! :) I found that using `__import__` and not needing to import the scripts by their names actually worked out nicely, because I could just iterate over the modules without needing their names.

Comment: Using exec() is overkill - you can just poke the loaded module into globals() and problem is solved.

Comment: Niall, can you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441909/python-module-not-defined-in-module-when-using-custom-load-function) for an alternative to using `exec`.

Comment: For some reason this fails when my modules attempt to import other modules within the package.

Comment: Is this just me or does this not work with relative imports? If I have `script1/file1.py` with the line `from .. import script2`, I get an error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

Comment: Also, can you do `from . import *` instead of the `exec` bit?

Comment: +1 to those who reported its incompatibility with relative imports within the package. I am facing the same problem. For me it says `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` when one of my submodule do `from .blah import Blah`.

Comment: I get a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` using this!

Comment: If you need relative imports to work: add `import importlib` and replace the line loading module with `_module = importlib.import_module('{}.{}'.format(__name__, module_name))`.

Comment: This answer should document that `__path__` is to be defined by the user. It is not automatic.

Answer (score 50):

This is based on [the answer that kolypto provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25083161/712522), but his answer does not perform recursive import of packages, whereas this does.  Although not required by the main question, I believe recursive import applies and can be very useful in many similar situations.  I, for one, found this question when searching on the topic.

This is a nice, clean way of performing the import of the subpackage's modules, and should be portable as well, and it uses the standard lib for python 2.7+ / 3.x.

```
import importlib
import pkgutil


def import_submodules(package, recursive=True):
    """ Import all submodules of a module, recursively, including subpackages

    :param package: package (name or actual module)
    :type package: str | module
    :rtype: dict[str, types.ModuleType]
    """
    if isinstance(package, str):
        package = importlib.import_module(package)
    results = {}
    for loader, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(package.__path__):
        full_name = package.__name__ + '.' + name
        try:
            results[full_name] = importlib.import_module(full_name)
        except ModuleNotFoundError:
            continue
        if recursive and is_pkg:
            results.update(import_submodules(full_name))
    return results
```

**Usage:**

```
# from main.py, as per the OP's project structure
import scripts
import_submodules(scripts)

# Alternatively, from scripts.__init__.py
import_submodules(__name__)
```

Comment: I believe [`pkgutil.walk_packages()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.walk_packages) is recursive on its own, so your function doesn't need to be recursive.

Comment: `pkgutil.walk_packages()` does claim to.  However, it does not do so.  Just run this on some package tree, with `recursive=True` and `recursive=False`.  You'll see the difference.

Comment: To make this more resilient, there are cases where a package is listed but not actually present so to guard against it: `try: results[full_name] = importlib.import_module(full_name)` and `except ModuleNotFoundError: continue`

Answer (score 19):

Simply works, and allows relative import inside packages:

```
def import_submodules(package_name):
    """ Import all submodules of a module, recursively

    :param package_name: Package name
    :type package_name: str
    :rtype: dict[types.ModuleType]
    """
    package = sys.modules[package_name]
    return {
        name: importlib.import_module(package_name + '.' + name)
        for loader, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(package.__path__)
    }
```

Usage:

```
__all__ = import_submodules(__name__).keys()
```

Answer (score 3):

To just *load* all submodules of a package, you can use this simple function:

```
import importlib
import pkgutil

def import_submodules(module):
    """Import all submodules of a module, recursively."""
    for loader, module_name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(
            module.__path__, module.__name__ + '.'):
        importlib.import_module(module_name)
```

Use case: load all database models of a Flask app, so that Flask-Migrate could detect changes to the schema. Usage:

```
import myproject.models
import_submodules(myproject.models)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got tired of this problem myself, so I wrote a package called automodinit to fix it. You can get it from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/automodinit/. Usage is like this:

1. Include the automodinit package into your `setup.py` dependencies.
2. Add the following to the beginning of the `__init__.py` file:

```
__all__ = ["I will get rewritten"]
# Don't modify the line above, or this line!
import automodinit
automodinit.automodinit(__name__, __file__, globals())
del automodinit
# Anything else you want can go after here, it won't get modified.
```

That's it! From now on importing a module will set `__all__` to
   a list of .py[co] files in the module and will also import each
   of those files as though you had typed:

```
for x in __all__: import x
```

Therefore the effect of `from M import *` matches exactly `import M`.

automodinit is happy running from inside ZIP archives and is therefore ZIP safe.

Answer (score 1):

Not nearly as clean as I would like, but none of the cleaner methods worked for me. This achieves the specified behaviour:

Directory structure:

```
| pkg
|--| __init__.py
   | main.py
   | scripts
   |--| __init__.py
      | script1.py
      | script2.py
      | script3.py
```

Where `pkg/scripts/__init__.py` is empty, and `pkg/__init__.py` contains:

```
import importlib as _importlib
import pkgutil as _pkgutil
__all__ = [_mod[1].split(".")[-1] for _mod in
           filter(lambda _mod: _mod[1].count(".") == 1 and not 
                               _mod[2] and __name__ in _mod[1],
                  [_mod for _mod in _pkgutil.walk_packages("." + __name__)])]
__sub_mods__ = [".".join(_mod[1].split(".")[1:]) for _mod in
                filter(lambda _mod: _mod[1].count(".") > 1 and not 
                                    _mod[2] and __name__ in _mod[1],
                       [_mod for _mod in 
                        _pkgutil.walk_packages("." + __name__)])]
from . import *
for _module in __sub_mods__:
    _importlib.import_module("." + _module, package=__name__)
```

Although it's messy, it should be portable. I've used this code for several different packages.

Comment: :-|  Just curious -- what about the cleaner methods didn't work?

Comment: Tbh, I don't remember.. sorry! The limitation may not even exist/apply anymore, so it's probably worth checking out. I'm not sure if it addresses the question, but nowadays I use `__all__ = [_mod[1] for _mod in _pkgutil.iter_modules(__path__) if not _mod[2]]`. I'm pretty sure the `iter_modules` function didn't exist back then.

Answer (score 0):

I was writing a small personal library and adding new modules all the time so I wrote a shell script to look for scripts and create the `__init__.py`'s. The script is executed just outside of the main directory for my package, pylux.

I know it probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but it servered its purpose for me and it might be useful to someone else, too.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Traversing folder hierarchy...'

CWD=`pwd`


for directory in `find pylux -type d -exec echo {} \;`;
do
    cd $directory
    #echo Entering $directory
    echo -n "" > __init__.py

    for subdirectory in `find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1`;
    do
        subdirectory=`echo $subdirectory | cut -b 3-`
        #echo -n '    ' ...$subdirectory
        #echo -e '\t->\t' import $subdirectory
        echo import $subdirectory >> __init__.py
    done

    for pyfile in *.py ;
    do
        if [ $pyfile = $(echo __init__.py) ]; then
            continue
        fi
        #echo -n '    ' ...$pyfile
        #echo -e '\t->\t' import `echo $pyfile | cut -d . -f 1`
        echo import `echo $pyfile | cut -d . -f 1` >> __init__.py
    done
    cd $CWD

done


for directory in `find pylux -type d -exec echo {} \;`;
do
    echo $directory/__init__.py:
    cat $directory/__init__.py | awk '{ print "\t"$0 }'
done
```

Comment: Couldn't the same logic be written in `__init__.py`? Using `os.listdir` and `__import__`?

Comment: Hmm. I suppose so, but I'd have to look into it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with [Joe Kington's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3365846/1110381) and have built a solution that uses `globals` and `get/setattr` and thus doesn't need eval. A slight modification is that instead of directly using the packages `__path__` for `walk_packages`, I use the packages parent directory and then only import modules starting with `__name__ + "."`. This was done to reliably get all subpackages from `walk_packages` - in my use case I had a subpackage named `test` which caused pkgutil to iterate over the `test` package from python's library; furthermore, using `__path__` would not recurse into the packages subdirectories. All these issues were observed using jython and python2.5, the code below is only tested in jython thus far.

Also note that OPs question only talks about importing all *modules* from a package, this code recursively imports all packages too.

```
from pkgutil import walk_packages
from os import path

__all__ = []
__pkg_prefix = "%s." % __name__
__pkg_path = path.abspath(__path__[0]).rsplit("/", 1)[0] #parent directory

for loader, modname, _ in walk_packages([__pkg_path]):
    if modname.startswith(__pkg_prefix):
        #load the module / package
        module = loader.find_module(modname).load_module(modname)
        modname = modname[len(__pkg_prefix):] #strip package prefix from name
        #append all toplevel modules and packages to __all__
        if not "." in modname:
            __all__.append(modname)
            globals()[modname] = module
        #set everything else as an attribute of their parent package
        else:
            #get the toplevel package from globals()
            pkg_name, rest = modname.split(".", 1)
            pkg = globals()[pkg_name]
            #recursively get the modules parent package via getattr
            while "." in rest:
                subpkg, rest = rest.split(".", 1)
                pkg = getattr(pkg, subpkg)
            #set the module (or package) as an attribute of its parent package
            setattr(pkg, rest, module)
```

As a future improvement I'll try to make this dynamic with a `__getattr__` hook on the package, so the actual modules are only imported when they are accessed...

Answer (score 0):

This works nicely for me in Python 3.3. Note that this works only for submodules which are in files in the same directory as the `__init__.py`. With some work however it can be enhanced for supporting submodules in directories too.

```
from glob import iglob
from os.path import basename, relpath, sep, splitext

def import_submodules(__path__to_here):
    """Imports all submodules.
    Import this function in __init__.py and put this line to it:
    __all__ = import_submodules(__path__)"""
    result = []
    for smfile in iglob(relpath(__path__to_here[0]) + "/*.py"):
        submodule = splitext(basename(smfile))[0]
        importstr = ".".join(smfile.split(sep)[:-1])
        if not submodule.startswith("_"):
            __import__(importstr + "." + submodule)
            result.append(submodule)
    return result
```