# How do I import all the submodules of a Python namespace package?

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

A Python namespace package can be spread over many directories, and zip files or custom importers. What's the correct way to iterate over all the importable submodules of a namespace package?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What have you tried?

Comment: You can use the pkgutil module. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365740/how-to-import-all-submodules

Comment: I am interested in using it for plugin enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way that works well for me.  Create a new submodule `all.py`, say, in one of the packages in the namespace.

If you write

```py
import mynamespace.all
```

you are given the object for the `mynamespace` module. This object contains all of the loaded modules in the namespace, irrespective of where they were loaded, since there is only one instance of `mynamespace` around.

So, just load all the packages in the namespace in `all.py`!

```py
# all.py

from pkgutil import iter_modules

# import this module's namespace (= parent) package
pkg = __import__(__package__)

# iterate all modules in pkg's paths,
# prefixing the returned module names with namespace-dot,
# and import the modules by name
for m in iter_modules(pkg.__path__, __package__ + '.'):
    __import__(m.name)
```

Or in a one-liner that keeps the `all` module empty, if you care about that sort of thing:

```py
# all.py

(lambda: [__import__(_.name) for _ in __import__('pkgutil').iter_modules(__import__(__package__).__path__, __package__ + '.')])()  # noqa
```

After importing the `all` module from your namespace, you then actually receive a fully populated namespace module:

```py
import mynamespace.all

mynamespace.mymodule1  # works
mynamespace.mymodule2  # works
...
```

Of course, you can use the same mechanism to enumerate or otherwise process the modules in the namespace, if you do not want to import them immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [import confusion](https://web.archive.org/web/20180713165523/http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm).

It very clearly distinguishes all the different ways you can import packages and its sub modules and in the process answers your question. When you need a certain submodule from a package, it’s often much more convenient to write `from io.drivers import zip` than `import io.drivers.zip`, since the former lets you refer to the module simply as zip instead of its full name.

`from modname import *`, this provides an easy way to import all the items from a module into the current namespace; however, this statement should be used sparingly.

Comment: I'm specifically not asking about "import *", when you "import *" from a namespace package nothing happens. Instead, I want to iterate through everything that I could import.

Comment: Using `*` imports is terrible practice. While it's valid python, it's almost always a bad idea outside of a few narrow cases.

Comment: Yes I do agree, as it reduces the time efficiency, but in situation where one does not know the particular module to be used , importing the entire package becomes the saviour.