# In Python how can one tell if a module comes from a C extension?

Tags: python, python-c-extension, extension-modules

What is the correct or most robust way to tell from Python if an imported module comes from a [C extension](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) as opposed to a pure Python module?  This is useful, for example, if a Python package has a module with both a pure Python implementation and a C implementation, and you want to be able to tell at runtime which one is being used.

One idea is to examine the file extension of `module.__file__`, but I'm not sure all the file extensions one should check for and if this approach is necessarily the most reliable.

Comment: c modules show up as "builtin". Use `dir`/check the docs to find out more.

Comment: Many modules are actually a thin Python wrapper around a C implementation if available, or around pure Python if not. Most of the 3.2+ stdlib works that way, and many of the most popular third-party modules as well. So, I suspect this won't actually tell you what you want. For example, `numpy` is a pure Python module, and `pickle` is pure Python whether `_Pickle` and friends come from the C accelerator or from pure Python.

Comment: @Marcin: 'show up as "builtin"' where? If you just look at the `repr` of, say, 2.7's `cPickle`, it has a pathname, not the string `built-in`. And the only official heuristic for distinguishing built-in modules is that `__file__` is  missing, which again is not true for `cPickle`.

Comment: @abarnert I am okay with addressing only the case of third-party modules in which an intervening pure Python wrapper is not being used.  In at least one such case I know of, the `__file__` attribute of the extension module ends with `.so` when the C implementation is being used, but I don't know if that is always or usually the case.

Comment: @cjerdonek: It's definitely not always the case. See my answer for full details.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, I don't think this is at all useful. It's very common for modules to be pure-Python wrappers around a C extension module—or, in some cases, pure-Python wrappers around a C extension module if it's available, or a pure Python implementation if not.

For some popular third-party examples: `numpy` is pure Python, even though everything important is implemented in C; `bintrees` is pure Python, even though its classes may all be implemented either in C or in Python depending on how you build it; etc.

And this is true in most of the stdlib from 3.2 on. For example, if you just `import pickle`, the implementation classes will be built in C (what you used to get from `cpickle` in 2.7) in CPython, while they'll be pure-Python versions in PyPy, but either way `pickle` itself is pure Python.

---

But if you *do* want to do this, you actually need to distinguish *three* things:

- Built-in modules, like `sys`.
- C extension modules, like 2.x's `cpickle`.
- Pure Python modules, like 2.x's `pickle`.

And that's assuming you only care about CPython; if your code runs in, say, Jython, or IronPython, the implementation could be JVM or .NET rather than native code.

You can't distinguish perfectly based on `__file__`, for a number of reasons:

- Built-in modules have no `__file__` at all. (This is documented in a few places—e.g., the [Types and members](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) table in the `inspect` docs.) Note that if you're using something like `py2app` or `cx_freeze`, what counts as "built-in" may be different from a standalone installation.
- A pure-Python module may have a .pyc/.pyo file without having a .py file in a distributed app.
- A module in a a package installed as a single-file egg (which is common with `easy_install`, less so with `pip`) will have either a blank or useless `__file__`.
- If you build a binary distribution, there's a good chance your whole library will be packed in a zip file, causing the same problem as single-file eggs.

---

In 3.1+, the import process has been massively cleaned up, mostly rewritten in Python, and mostly exposed to the Python layer.

So, you can use the [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) module to see the chain of loaders used to load a module, and ultimately you'll get to `BuiltinImporter` (builtins), `ExtensionFileLoader` (.so/.pyd/etc.), `SourceFileLoader` (.py), or `SourcelessFileLoader` (.pyc/.pyo).

You can also see the suffixes assigned to each of the four, on the current target platform, as constants in `importlib.machinery`. So, you *could* check that the `any(pathname.endswith(suffix) for suffix in importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES))`, but that won't actually help in, e.g., the egg/zip case unless you've already traveled up the chain anyway.

---

The best heuristics anyone has come up with for this are the ones implemented in the `inspect` module, so the best thing to do is to use that.

The best choice will be one or more of `getsource`, `getsourcefile`, and `getfile`; which is best depends on which heuristics you want.

A built-in module will raise a `TypeError` for any of them.

An extension module ought to return an empty string for `getsourcefile`. This seems to work in all the 2.5-3.4 versions I have, but I don't have 2.4 around. For `getsource`, at least in some versions, it returns the actual bytes of the .so file, even though it should be returning an empty string or raising an `IOError`. (In 3.x, you will almost certainly get a `UnicodeError` or `SyntaxError`, but you probably don't want to rely on that…)

Pure Python modules may return an empty string for `getsourcefile` if in an egg/zip/etc. They should always return a non-empty string for `getsource` if source is available, even inside an egg/zip/etc., but if they're sourceless bytecode (.pyc/etc.) they will return an empty string or raise an IOError.

The best bet is to experiment with the version you care about on the platform(s) you care about in the distribution/setup(s) you care about.

Comment: Even inspect.getsource not work well, For binary module, it return binary ELF string content, for Pure py, it return source code. Test on RedHat EL5, python 2.4.3. And EL6, python 2.6.6. Is that too old?

Comment: @PasteBT: It really shouldn't be returning the ELF string content… let me scan through the history to see if that's changed at some point. Maybe you want to use `getsourcefile` and/or `getsourcelines` directly?

Comment: Fedora 17 + python 2.7.3 works. Binary module raise exception. And getsourcefile match better to your description. Even for older version

Comment: @PasteBT: I reproduced binary modules returning binary "source" in 2.5 and 3.1, although in 3.1 you get a `UnicodeError` or `SyntaxError` trying to treat the Mach-O/ELF/PE header as text. However, at least in 2.7 and 3.4, `getsource` sometimes works for zipped source files where `getsourcefile` does not. So, they both have advantages and disadvantages, and there is no perfect answer.

Comment: **There _is_ a perfect answer,** but neither the stdlib `inspect` nor `importlib` modules are it. Why? Because the values returned by `inspect.getsource()` _and_ `inspect.getsourcefile()` fail to distinguish between C extensions (_which have no pure-Python source_) and other types of modules _also_ having no pure-Python source (e.g., bytecode-only modules). Likewise, `importlib` machinery only applies to modules loadable with PEP 302-compliant loaders – which is _not_ necessarily the case. Nonetheless, this answer is excellent for its exploration of non-obvious nuance.

Comment: Here's a scenario where it's more than useful, it's necessary: AWS Lambda functions. Lambda has some libs pre-installed.   The runtime container is evanescent, so there's no way to install more.  You can "vendor" libs into the Lambda package, and add those dirs to `sys.path` at run time.  Odd but works well.  The twist is with platform-specific libs.  Pure libs can be copied in from whatever OS you developing in, but OS-specific ones need to be built in another Amazon Linux instance and copied into your vendor folders.  That's a PITA so you only want to do it for non-pure-Python libraries.

Comment: Is there a typo for the first paragarph or is it just me getting it wrong? *"It's very common for modules to **be pure-Python wrappers around a C extension module** —or, in some cases, **pure-Python wrappers around a C extension module** if it's available, or a pure Python implementation if not."* The emphasized repeats twice and is talking the same thing.

Answer (score 30):

> **tl;dr**
>
> See the "In Search of Perfection" subsection below for the well-tested answer.

As a pragmatic counterpoint to [abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert)'s [helpful analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20339418/2809027) of the subtlety involved in portably identifying C extensions, Stack Overflow Productions™ presents... **an actual answer.**

The capacity to reliably differentiate C extensions from non-C extensions is incredibly useful, without which the Python community would be impoverished. Real-world use cases include:

- **Application freezing,** converting one cross-platform Python codebase into multiple platform-specific executables. [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) is the standard example here. Identifying C extensions is critical to robust freezing. If a module imported by the codebase being frozen is a C extension, all external shared libraries transitively linked to by that C extension *must* be frozen with that codebase as well. <sup>*Shameful confession: I [contribute](http://github.com/leycec) to PyInstaller.*</sup>
- **Application optimization,** either statically to native machine code (e.g., [Cython](http://cython.org)) *or* dynamically in a just-in-time manner (e.g., [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org)). For self-evident reasons, Python optimizers necessarily differentiate already compiled C extensions from uncompiled pure-Python modules.
- **Dependency analysis,** inspecting external shared libraries on behalf of end users. In [our case](https://gitlab.com/betse/betse), we analyze a mandatory dependency ([Numpy](http://www.numpy.org)) to detect local installations of this dependency linking against non-parallelized shared libraries (e.g., the [reference BLAS implementation](http://www.netlib.org/blas)) and inform end users when this is the case. Why? Because we don't want the blame when our application underperforms due to improper installation of dependencies over which we have no control. <sup>*Bad performance is your fault, hapless user!*</sup>
- **Probably other essential low-level stuff.** Profiling, maybe?

We can all agree that freezing, optimization, and minimizing end user complaints are useful. Ergo, identifying C extensions is useful.

### The Disagreement Deepens

I also disagree with [abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert)'s penultimate conclusion that:

> The best heuristics anyone has come up with for this are the ones implemented in the `inspect` module, so the best thing to do is to use that.

**No.** The best heuristics anyone has come up with for this are those given below. All stdlib modules (including but *not* limited to `inspect`) are useless for this purpose. Specifically:

- The `inspect.getsource()` and `inspect.getsourcefile()` functions ambiguously return `None` for both C extensions (which understandably have no pure-Python source) and other types of modules that also have no pure-Python source (e.g., bytecode-only modules). *Useless*.
- `importlib` machinery *only* applies to modules loadable by [PEP 302-compliant loaders](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302) and hence visible to the default `importlib` import algorithm. *Useful,* but hardly generally applicable. The assumption of PEP 302 compliance breaks down when the real world hits your package in the face repeatedly. For example, did you know that the `__import__()` built-in is actually [overriddable](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#id24)? <sup>*This is how we used to customize Python's import mechanism – back when the Earth was still flat.*</sup>

[abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert)'s [ultimate conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339053/in-python-how-can-one-tell-if-a-module-comes-from-a-c-extension#comment30359399_20339418) is also contentious:

> …there is no perfect answer.

There is a perfect answer. Much like the oft-doubted [Triforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triforce) of Hyrulean legend, a perfect answer exists for every imperfect question.

Let's find it.

### In Search of Perfection

The pure-Python function that follows returns `True` only if the passed previously imported module object is a C extension: <sup>*For simplicity, **Python 3.x** is assumed.*</sup>

```
import inspect, os
from importlib.machinery import ExtensionFileLoader, EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
from types import ModuleType

def is_c_extension(module: ModuleType) -> bool:
    '''
    `True` only if the passed module is a C extension implemented as a
    dynamically linked shared library specific to the current platform.

    Parameters
    ----------
    module : ModuleType
        Previously imported module object to be tested.

    Returns
    ----------
    bool
        `True` only if this module is a C extension.
    '''
    assert isinstance(module, ModuleType), '"{}" not a module.'.format(module)

    # If this module was loaded by a PEP 302-compliant CPython-specific loader
    # loading only C extensions, this module is a C extension.
    if isinstance(getattr(module, '__loader__', None), ExtensionFileLoader):
        return True

    # Else, fallback to filetype matching heuristics.
    #
    # Absolute path of the file defining this module.
    module_filename = inspect.getfile(module)

    # "."-prefixed filetype of this path if any or the empty string otherwise.
    module_filetype = os.path.splitext(module_filename)[1]

    # This module is only a C extension if this path's filetype is that of a
    # C extension specific to the current platform.
    return module_filetype in EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
```

If it looks long, that's because docstrings, comments, and assertions are good. It's actually only six lines. *Eat your elderly heart out, Guido.*

### Proof in the Pudding

Let's unit test this function with four portably importable modules:

- The stdlib pure-Python `os.__init__` module. <sup>*Hopefully not a C extension.*</sup>
- The stdlib pure-Python `importlib.machinery` submodule. <sup>*Hopefully not a C extension.*</sup>
- The stdlib `_elementtree` C extension.
- The third-party `numpy.core.multiarray` C extension.

To wit:

```
>>> import os
>>> import importlib.machinery as im
>>> import _elementtree as et
>>> import numpy.core.multiarray as ma
>>> for module in (os, im, et, ma):
...     print('Is "{}" a C extension? {}'.format(
...         module.__name__, is_c_extension(module)))
Is "os" a C extension? False
Is "importlib.machinery" a C extension? False
Is "_elementtree" a C extension? True
Is "numpy.core.multiarray" a C extension? True
```

All's well that ends.

### How to do this?

The details of our code are quite inconsequential. Very well, where do we begin?

1. If the passed module was loaded by a PEP 302-compliant loader (*the common case*), the [PEP 302 specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302) requires the attribute assigned on importation to this module to define a special `__loader__` attribute whose value is the loader object loading this module. Hence:

   1. If this value for this module is an instance of the CPython-specific `importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader` class, this module is a C extension.
2. Else, either **(A)** the active Python interpreter is *not* the official CPython implementation (e.g., [PyPy](http://pypy.org)) or **(B)** the active Python interpreter is CPython but this module was *not* loaded by a PEP 302-compliant loader, typically due to the default `__import__()` machinery being overridden (e.g., by a low-level bootloader running this Python application as a platform-specific frozen binary). In either case, fallback to testing whether this module's filetype is that of a C extension specific to the current platform.

Eight line functions with twenty page explanations. *Thas just how we rolls.*

Answer (score 4):

@Cecil Curry's function is excellent. Two minor comments: firsly, the `_elementtree` example raises a `TypeError` with my copy of Python 3.5.6. Secondly, as @crld points out, it's also helpful to know if a module *contains* C extensions, but a more portable version might help. More generic versions (with Python 3.6+ f-string syntax) may therefore be:

```
from importlib.machinery import ExtensionFileLoader, EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
import inspect
import logging
import os
import os.path
import pkgutil
from types import ModuleType
from typing import List

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def is_builtin_module(module: ModuleType) -> bool:
    """
    Is this module a built-in module, like ``os``?
    Method is as per :func:`inspect.getfile`.
    """
    return not hasattr(module, "__file__")


def is_module_a_package(module: ModuleType) -> bool:
    assert inspect.ismodule(module)
    return os.path.basename(inspect.getfile(module)) == "__init__.py"


def is_c_extension(module: ModuleType) -> bool:
    """
    Modified from
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339053/in-python-how-can-one-tell-if-a-module-comes-from-a-c-extension.

    ``True`` only if the passed module is a C extension implemented as a
    dynamically linked shared library specific to the current platform.

    Args:
        module: Previously imported module object to be tested.

    Returns:
        bool: ``True`` only if this module is a C extension.

    Examples:

    .. code-block:: python

        from cardinal_pythonlib.modules import is_c_extension

        import os
        import _elementtree as et
        import numpy
        import numpy.core.multiarray as numpy_multiarray

        is_c_extension(os)  # False
        is_c_extension(numpy)  # False
        is_c_extension(et)  # False on my system (Python 3.5.6). True in the original example.
        is_c_extension(numpy_multiarray)  # True

    """  # noqa
    assert inspect.ismodule(module), f'"{module}" not a module.'

    # If this module was loaded by a PEP 302-compliant CPython-specific loader
    # loading only C extensions, this module is a C extension.
    if isinstance(getattr(module, '__loader__', None), ExtensionFileLoader):
        return True

    # If it's built-in, it's not a C extension.
    if is_builtin_module(module):
        return False

    # Else, fallback to filetype matching heuristics.
    #
    # Absolute path of the file defining this module.
    module_filename = inspect.getfile(module)

    # "."-prefixed filetype of this path if any or the empty string otherwise.
    module_filetype = os.path.splitext(module_filename)[1]

    # This module is only a C extension if this path's filetype is that of a
    # C extension specific to the current platform.
    return module_filetype in EXTENSION_SUFFIXES


def contains_c_extension(module: ModuleType,
                         import_all_submodules: bool = True,
                         include_external_imports: bool = False,
                         seen: List[ModuleType] = None,
                         verbose: bool = False) -> bool:
    """
    Extends :func:`is_c_extension` by asking: is this module, or any of its
    submodules, a C extension?

    Args:
        module: Previously imported module object to be tested.
        import_all_submodules: explicitly import all submodules of this module?
        include_external_imports: check modules in other packages that this
            module imports?
        seen: used internally for recursion (to deal with recursive modules);
            should be ``None`` when called by users
        verbose: show working via log?

    Returns:
        bool: ``True`` only if this module or one of its submodules is a C
        extension.

    Examples:

    .. code-block:: python

        import logging

        import _elementtree as et
        import os

        import arrow
        import alembic
        import django
        import numpy
        import numpy.core.multiarray as numpy_multiarray

        log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)  # be verbose

        contains_c_extension(os)  # False
        contains_c_extension(et)  # False

        contains_c_extension(numpy)  # True -- different from is_c_extension()
        contains_c_extension(numpy_multiarray)  # True

        contains_c_extension(arrow)  # False

        contains_c_extension(alembic)  # False
        contains_c_extension(alembic, include_external_imports=True)  # True
        # ... this example shows that Alembic imports hashlib, which can import
        #     _hashlib, which is a C extension; however, that doesn't stop us (for
        #     example) installing Alembic on a machine with no C compiler

        contains_c_extension(django)

    """  # noqa
    assert inspect.ismodule(module), f'"{module}" not a module.'

    if seen is None:  # only true for the top-level call
        seen = []  # type: List[ModuleType]
    if module in seen:  # modules can "contain" themselves
        # already inspected; avoid infinite loops
        return False
    seen.append(module)

    # Check the thing we were asked about
    is_c_ext = is_c_extension(module)
    if verbose:
        log.info(f"Is module {module!r} a C extension? {is_c_ext}")
    if is_c_ext:
        return True
    if is_builtin_module(module):
        # built-in, therefore we stop searching it
        return False

    # Now check any children, in a couple of ways

    top_level_module = seen[0]
    top_path = os.path.dirname(top_level_module.__file__)

    # Recurse using dir(). This picks up modules that are automatically
    # imported by our top-level model. But it won't pick up all submodules;
    # try e.g. for django.
    for candidate_name in dir(module):
        candidate = getattr(module, candidate_name)
        # noinspection PyBroadException
        try:
            if not inspect.ismodule(candidate):
                # not a module
                continue
        except Exception:
            # e.g. a Django module that won't import until we configure its
            # settings
            log.error(f"Failed to test ismodule() status of {candidate!r}")
            continue
        if is_builtin_module(candidate):
            # built-in, therefore we stop searching it
            continue

        candidate_fname = getattr(candidate, "__file__")
        if not include_external_imports:
            if os.path.commonpath([top_path, candidate_fname]) != top_path:
                if verbose:
                    log.debug(f"Skipping, not within the top-level module's "
                              f"directory: {candidate!r}")
                continue
        # Recurse:
        if contains_c_extension(
                module=candidate,
                import_all_submodules=False,  # only done at the top level, below  # noqa
                include_external_imports=include_external_imports,
                seen=seen):
            return True

    if import_all_submodules:
        if not is_module_a_package(module):
            if verbose:
                log.debug(f"Top-level module is not a package: {module!r}")
            return False

        # Otherwise, for things like Django, we need to recurse in a different
        # way to scan everything.
        # See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365740/how-to-import-all-submodules.  # noqa
        log.debug(f"Walking path: {top_path!r}")
        try:
            for loader, module_name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages([top_path]):  # noqa
                if not is_pkg:
                    log.debug(f"Skipping, not a package: {module_name!r}")
                    continue
                log.debug(f"Manually importing: {module_name!r}")
                # noinspection PyBroadException
                try:
                    candidate = loader.find_module(module_name)\
                        .load_module(module_name)  # noqa
                except Exception:
                    # e.g. Alembic "autogenerate" gives: "ValueError: attempted
                    # relative import beyond top-level package"; or Django
                    # "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured"
                    log.error(f"Package failed to import: {module_name!r}")
                    continue
                if contains_c_extension(
                        module=candidate,
                        import_all_submodules=False,  # only done at the top level  # noqa
                        include_external_imports=include_external_imports,
                        seen=seen):
                    return True
        except Exception:
            log.error("Unable to walk packages further; no C extensions "
                      "detected so far!")
            raise

    return False


# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences,PyTypeChecker
def test() -> None:
    import _elementtree as et

    import arrow
    import alembic
    import django
    import django.conf
    import numpy
    import numpy.core.multiarray as numpy_multiarray

    log.info(f"contains_c_extension(os): "
             f"{contains_c_extension(os)}")  # False
    log.info(f"contains_c_extension(et): "
             f"{contains_c_extension(et)}")  # False

    log.info(f"is_c_extension(numpy): "
             f"{is_c_extension(numpy)}")  # False
    log.info(f"contains_c_extension(numpy): "
             f"{contains_c_extension(numpy)}")  # True
    log.info(f"contains_c_extension(numpy_multiarray): "
             f"{contains_c_extension(numpy_multiarray)}")  # True  # noqa

    log.info(f"contains_c_extension(arrow): "
             f"{contains_c_extension(arrow)}")  # False

    log.info(f"contains_c_extension(alembic): "
             f"{contains_c_extension(alembic)}")  # False
    log.info(f"contains_c_extension(alembic, include_external_imports=True): "
             f"{contains_c_extension(alembic, include_external_imports=True)}")  # True  # noqa
    # ... this example shows that Alembic imports hashlib, which can import
    #     _hashlib, which is a C extension; however, that doesn't stop us (for
    #     example) installing Alembic on a machine with no C compiler

    django.conf.settings.configure()
    log.info(f"contains_c_extension(django): "
             f"{contains_c_extension(django)}")  # False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)  # be verbose
    test()
```

Comment: The snippet fails since
1) the `log` object is missing (fix by adding e.g. `import logging ; log = logging.getLogger(__name__)`), and
2) the `is_module_a_package()` function is missing (I don't know how to implement it)

Comment: Thanks -- edited accordingly; example is now self-contained and tested under Python 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

While [Cecil Curry's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2809027/cecil-curry]) answer works (and was very informative, as was [abarnert's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert), I might add) it will return False for the "top level" of a module even if it includes sub-modules that use the C extension (e.g. numpy vs. numpy.core.multiarray).

While probably not as robust as it could be, the following is working for my use current use cases:

```
def is_c(module):

    # if module is part of the main python library (e.g. os), it won't have a path
    try:
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(module.__path__[0]):

            for f in files:
                ftype = f.split('.')[-1]
                if ftype == 'so':
                    is_c = True
                    break
        return is_c

    except AttributeError:

        path = inspect.getfile(module)
        suffix = path.split('.')[-1]

        if suffix != 'so':

            return False

        elif suffix == 'so':

            return True

is_c(os), is_c(im), is_c(et), is_c_extension(ma), is_c(numpy)
# (False, False, True, True, True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you, like me, saw @Cecil Curry' s great answer and thought, how could I do this for an entire requirements file in a super lazy way without @Rudolf Cardinal's complex child library traversal, look no further!

First, dump all your installed requirements (assuming you did this in a virtual env and don't have other stuff in here) into a file with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

Then run the following script to check each of those requirements.

Note: this is super lazy and WILL NOT work for many libraries who's import names don't match their pip names.

```
import inspect, os
import importlib
from importlib.machinery import ExtensionFileLoader, EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
from types import ModuleType

# function from Cecil Curry's answer:

def is_c_extension(module: ModuleType) -> bool:
    '''
    `True` only if the passed module is a C extension implemented as a
    dynamically linked shared library specific to the current platform.

    Parameters
    ----------
    module : ModuleType
        Previously imported module object to be tested.

    Returns
    ----------
    bool
        `True` only if this module is a C extension.
    '''
    assert isinstance(module, ModuleType), '"{}" not a module.'.format(module)

    # If this module was loaded by a PEP 302-compliant CPython-specific loader
    # loading only C extensions, this module is a C extension.
    if isinstance(getattr(module, '__loader__', None), ExtensionFileLoader):
        return True

    # Else, fallback to filetype matching heuristics.
    #
    # Absolute path of the file defining this module.
    module_filename = inspect.getfile(module)

    # "."-prefixed filetype of this path if any or the empty string otherwise.
    module_filetype = os.path.splitext(module_filename)[1]

    # This module is only a C extension if this path's filetype is that of a
    # C extension specific to the current platform.
    return module_filetype in EXTENSION_SUFFIXES


with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        # super lazy pip name to library name conversion
        # there is probably a better way to do this.
        lib = line.split("=")[0].replace("python-","").replace("-","_").lower()
        try:
            mod = importlib.import_module(lib)
            print(f"is {lib} a c extension? : {is_c_extension(mod)}")
        except:
            print(f"could not check {lib}, perhaps the name for imports is different?")
```