# Check if class object is defined in extension module

Tags: python, cython, python-internals, python-extensions, function-signature

Given a class object in Python, how can I determine if the class was defined in an extension module (e.g. c, c++, cython), as opposed to being defined in standard python?

`inspect.isbuiltin` returns `True` for *functions* defined in an extension module, and `False` for functions defined in python, but it unfortunately does not have the same behavior for classes -- it returns `False` for both kinds of classes.

(The larger goal here is that we've got a system that generates a command line API for a set of classes based on parsing the docstring and signature of their `__init__` functions. This system fails for classes defined in cython because `inspect.getargspec` doesn't work correctly on these classes, so I'm trying to figure out a workaround)

Comment: You could `try` something that will fail for objects not implemented in Python (e.g. `inspect.getsourcelines`) and catch the error.

Comment: What *specifically* do you need to know this for?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I added a description of the larger goal to the question.

Answer (score 0):

"This system fails for classes defined in cython because X"

Doesn't this mean that the answer you're looking for is X?

To know if a class is of the kind that crashes some function, like when you do `inspect.getargspec(X.__init__)`, then just do `inspect.getargspec(X.__init__)` in a `try: except` block.

Comment: It doesn't fail properly, it just returns the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, struggled with this – I ended up writing a series of functions to solve the problem of whether or not something is native, to cover the corner-cases:

```py
import importlib
import importlib.machinery
import inspect

QUALIFIER = '.'

EXTENSION_SUFFIXES = tuple(suffix.lstrip(QUALIFIER) \
                       for suffix \
                        in importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES)

moduleof = lambda thing: getattr(thing, '__module__', '')

isbuiltin = lambda thing: moduleof(thing) == 'builtins'

suffix = lambda filename: QUALIFIER in filename \
            and filename.rpartition(QUALIFIER)[-1] \
             or ''

def isnativemodule(module):
    """ isnativemodule(thing) → boolean predicate, True if `module`
        is a native-compiled (“extension”) module.

        Q.v. this fine StackOverflow answer on this subject:
            https://stackoverflow.com/a/39304199/298171
    """
    # Step one: modules only beyond this point:
    if not inspect.ismodule(module):
        return False

    # Step two: return truly when “__loader__” is set:
    if isinstance(getattr(module, '__loader__', None),
                  importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader):
        return True

    # Step three: in leu of either of those indicators,
    # check the module path’s file suffix:
    try:
        ext = suffix(inspect.getfile(module))
    except TypeError as exc:
        return 'is a built-in' in str(exc)

    return ext in EXTENSION_SUFFIXES

def isnative(thing):
    """ isnative(thing) → boolean predicate, True if `thing`
        comes from a native-compiled (“extension”) module.
    """
    module = moduleof(thing)
    # You can have this next line return “True”,
    # if that covers your use-cases, and thus get rid
    # of “isinspectable(…)”, below:
    if module == 'builtins':
        return False
    return isnativemodule(
           importlib.import_module(
                            module))

def isinspectable(thing):
    """ isinspectable(thing) → boolean predicate, True
        if `thing` is inspectable, through the “inspect”
        modules’ myriad functions and types.
    """
    return (not isbuiltin(thing)) \
       and (not isnative(thing))
```

… As noted: the source for the `isnativemodule(…)` function, above, originally came from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39304199/298171) (which also may be of use to you). The code as written [is adapted](https://github.com/fish2000/CLU/blob/bf2de05ed647ff1eb54b7cd32cd250c0cf285c92/clu/naming.py#L124-L184) from [CLU, my utility-drawer library package](https://github.com/fish2000/CLU).

…I also have [code that parses](https://github.com/fish2000/CLU/blob/bf2de05ed647ff1eb54b7cd32cd250c0cf285c92/clu/repl/ansi.py#L488-L501) and [displays function signatures](https://github.com/fish2000/CLU/blob/bf2de05ed647ff1eb54b7cd32cd250c0cf285c92/clu/repl/ansi.py#L685-L703), which, as you seek to do with your project, does leverage these predicate functions. Just like FYI