# How to tell if my Python packages use C extensions?

Tags: python, django

I am considering using the [shiv package](https://shiv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) as a way to create a Python zipapp of my Django project (rather than resorting to Docker).  It's my understanding that this approach is not feasible if any of my Python packages have C extensions.  Is there any tool that could examine my pip requirements file and tell me if any of the packages it contains (as well as their dependencies) utilize C extensions?

I know that the Python interpreter is written in C so I would imagine many Python packages are written in C as well (or perhaps not?).  So if this sounds like a stupid question, it's because I don't understand what the difference is between a program like the Python interpreter that is written in C and what a C extension is as I've never studied the C language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been asked before, and there is really no simple answer:

[In Python how can one tell if a module comes from a C extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339053/in-python-how-can-one-tell-if-a-module-comes-from-a-c-extension)

But it's important to note that the use of shiv with C modules is not an impossibility. If your target host is the same architecture as the host you build the package on, you should have no problems.