# Import all modules from the package

Tags: python, import, package

I have a Python package with several modules.

**What I can do:**

It's possible to use all modules from the package in my program by modifying `__init__.py` of the package, by importing all modules in it:

```
#__init__.py
import module1
import module2
```

Then I simply import package in my program and can access classes/functions in all the modules by their full name

```
#My program
import package
a = package.module1.A()
```

**QUESTION:**

Is there any way to automate addition of imports to `__init__.py` so I don't need to specify them manually?

Comment: No. (10 more to go...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import all submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365740/how-to-import-all-submodules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another answer that might be closer to what you want.

In `__init__.py` you can add this to import all python files in the package.

> *Note that it doesn't do packages.. not sure how. And I'm using windows*

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import abspath, dirname, isfile, join
# get location of __init__.py
init_path = abspath(__file__)
# get folder name of __init__.py
init_dir = dirname(init_path)
# get all python files
py_files = [file_name.replace(".py", "") for file_name in listdir(init_dir) \
           if isfile(join(init_dir, file_name)) and ".py" in file_name and not ".pyc" in file_name]
# remove this __init__ file from the list
py_files.remove("__init__")

__all__ = py_files
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna try it and be back with the results

Answer (score 3):

The init file doesn't work like that.. I think you're thinking of something like this..

if you have the file structure:

```
my_program.py
/my_package
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
```

in `__init__.py` you can write this line to edit the way `import *` works for `my_package`

```
__all__ = ["module1", "module2"]
```

now in `my_program.py` you can do this:

```
from my_package import *
a = module1.A()
```

Hope that helps!
You can read more here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

Comment: The way I described works indeed. The method you described should work fine too. However, it's again manually adding all the modules into package.

Comment: @Konstantin I meant the "automate addition of imports" part. Unless you want to use the `os` module to walk through the package directory and add all the found py files to the `__all__` list.

Comment: Can I do it in a way PyDev or any other IDE still handles autocompletion?

Comment: @Konstantin Not sure about the IDE side of things. I do all my writing in notepad++ so I'm not much help in that regard :p

Comment: I upvoted your reply, but still believe that someone may already solve the issue and may help me)

Comment: @Konstantin No worries, Mate!