# Python: How do I import modules without python-filename as submodule?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

### Description

Assume, I have a package with the following structure:

```
package-folder
  |_ mypackage
     |_ __init__.py
     |_ module1.py
  setup.py
```

Where `__init__.py` is empty and

`module1.py`:

```
def do_stuff():
    print('Did stuff.')
```

`setup.py` is containing the usual context for making a package out of this, which can be installed with `pip install -e pkgpath` on the local system.

In a `script.py`, I would have to do:

```
import mypackage as abbr

abbr.module1.do_stuff()
# output: Did stuff.
```

My desired call would be:

```
abbr.do_stuff()
# output: Did stuff.
```

### Questions

1. How can I 'organize' my package so that I can call functions, out of module1.py directly from `abbr.function()`? What code changes are required?
2. Is this organization useful if the package grows? So that directories would act as the structure-element and python-files are just capsules to organize my functions within?
3. What is the best way to organize functions in modules and sub-modules?

---

### Further thoughts

- Is there a good reason not to have just one function in each python-file which can be used from the module? (and has the same name as the file)
- I assume, I will have to modify my `__init__.py`-files, but I couldn't figure out how.

### Clarification on questions 2

```
package-folder
|_ mypackage
   |_ __init__.py
   |_ module1.py #with function do_stuff1()
   |_ subpackage
      |_module2.py #with function do_stuff2()
setup.py
```

Calls should be:

```
abbr.do_stuff1()
abbr.subpackage.do_stuff2()
```

And **not**:

```
abbr.module1.do_stuff1()
abbr.subpackage.module2.do_stuff2()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got quite close to the answer, you just needed to import the methods from `__init__.py`.

You can also add the special variable `__all__` that is a list of the variable/functions/etc that the user can expect to find in that file.

`__init__.py` @ `mypackage`

```
from .module1 import do_stuff1

__all__ = ['do_stuff1']
```

`__init__.py` @ `subpackage`

```
from .module2 import do_stuff2

__all__ = ['do_stuff2']
```

## EDIT:

To make your top-level package import all the subpackage symbols you could change `__init__.py` @ `mypackage` to:

```
import pkgutil

from .module1 import do_stuff1

__all__ = ['do_stuff']

for loader, name, is_pkg in  pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
    module = loader.find_module(name).load_module(name)
    __all__.extend(module.__all__)
    for var in module.__all__:
        globals()[var] = getattr(module, var)
```

Then you will not only be able to call `abbr.subpackage.do_stuuf2()` but also `abbr.do_stuuf2()`.

Comment: Your solutions works, concerning the question 1! Great!
But wouldn't this get a bit messy, with a 'big' package? Isn't there a better way to do that?
Also, in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365740/how-to-import-all-submodules) was a code snipped suggested, which should load 'all' submodules, but I couldn't get it to work.
Besides that, some 'guides' recommend to better leave your __init__.py empty.
Last comment: But what is the 'best' way to do it?

Comment: I wouldn't consider leaving `__init__.py` empty a recomendation, it's more a option you have, but it gives you a really powerfull way of offering easy object access while keeping the code in an organized fashion. I do use scripts instead of manual imports in some `__init__.py` but only too flattern subpackages, this is, being able to do `abbr.do_stuff2()`.

Comment: Could you give an example script, you use for that?

Comment: @Laenan I do not have a copy of the script on me right now, but I basically iter over all the subpackages (directories) importing all that its in their __all__ variable into the main package.

Comment: @Laenan I added an unchecked script to my answer, check if that works for you. It will basically get everything in the `__all__` variable of subpackages and also place in the package `__all__`.

Comment: Hey thanks @Adirio! Will have a look into that on monday.

Comment: Hey, tested a bunch of stuff. Works fine for minimal example, but not in my code. But your first answer is sufficient for my problem. :-) Thank's again!