# import submodules automatically

Tags: python-3.x, import

I am writing a simple python module of the form

```
toys/
    A.py
    B.py
    .
    .
    .
```

My goal is to be able to access any toy in toys as simply as `import toys` such that `toy.A` exists. But `dir(toys)` does not include A, given the directory structure shown above. Instead, I have to import each toy individually, `import toy.A`.

Of course I can force each toy to be included by including `from . import A` in `toy/__init__.py`. But I'm trying to set up a workflow in which I add arbitrarily many toys; having to add a line explicitly for each new toy is cumbersome. How can I implicitly attach each new toy to `toys`? Is there a graceful way to attach a module's submodules automatically?

I tried putting `from . import *` inside of `__init__.py`, but this had no effect, not to mention that it's considered an antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

A minor tweak to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3365846/2232265) to make it non-recursive is

```
import pkgutil

__all__ = []
for loader, module_name, is_pkg in  pkgutil.iter_modules(__path__):
    __all__.append(module_name)
    _module = loader.find_module(module_name).load_module(module_name)
    globals()[module_name] = _module
```

which seems to work, but I would not call it graceful.