# How to import all modules in __init.py__ in python?

Tags: python

I have a directory that contains several .py files/modules. In that directory, I put `__init__.py` within with an intent to make it a package. What I would like to have is, when I import the directory, I would access all the methods from individual modules without specifying each module name inside `__init__.py`. This means, when I would add a new module, `__init__.py` would pick it up and I am free off manual update of that module name inside of `__init__.py`. Here is an example to show what I want:

```
/my_package/
   module1.py
   module2.py
   ..........
   ..........
   moduleN.py
```

Now,

within `module1.py`, I have `def add(n,m):`

within `module2.py`, I have `def sub(n,m):`
     etc. etc.

Now, suppose in Jupyter lab, I import like this,

```
import my_package as mpgk
```

then I would like to access `mpkg.add`, `mpkg.sub`

What do I need to do inside `__init__.py` to make sure the methods from individual modules from that directory are loaded?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should use `code` sections to format your question. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why not just use `from my_package.module1 import *`?

Comment: `from module1 import *` etc to refer to the functions/classes from the module1 directly. | As for picking up every module, even a new one... that's more complicated. Why do you even need this? This seems like a bad design. Firstly, name collisions. Secondly, it looks like Java approach "everything in a different file", and this is not Java, it's Python, we do things differently here. (Basically, why even have modules if you're gonna import everything at once without exceptions???)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import all submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365740/how-to-import-all-submodules)