# Correct way to re-export modules from __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a *plugins* package that contains several modules, each defining one class (each class is a *plugin*).

My package structure looks like this :

```
plugins
├ __init__.py
├ first_plugin.py
├ second_plugin.py
└ third_plugin.py
```

And a plugin file typically looks like this, only containing a class definition (and a few imports if necessary) :

```py
# in first_plugin.py

class MyFirstPlugin:
    ...
```

I would like the end user to be able to import a plugin like so :

```py
from plugins import FirstPlugin
```

instead of having to also type the module name (which is what is currently required to do) :

```py
from plugins.first_plugin import FirstPlugin
```

Is there a way to achieve this by re-exporting the modules' classes directly in the __init__.py file **without** having to import everything module by module like so (which becomes cumbersome when there are lots of modules)  :

```py
# in __init__.py

from .first_plugin import FirstPlugin
from .second_plugin import SecondPlugin
from .third_plugin import ThirdPlugin
```

Comment: Since all your plugins are in a package, my answer to [How to import members of all modules within a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426574/how-to-import-members-of-all-modules-within-a-package) might help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Just wondering if you figured out and found a solution to this?

Comment: I didn't really find anything satisfying... I think I had a few ideas of "hacks" using `dir()` and filtering by module name (which can be accessed as a `str` in Python), but it quickly gets dirty.

Comment: Sigh... Another problem is that linters will complain about `from .first_plugin import FirstPlugin` in `__init__.py`, because `FirstPlugin` isn't used.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think this is possible in Python. However you can import entire modules so you do not have to import each class individually.

For example

```py
from first_plugin import *
```

Allowing you to do

```py
from plugin import # Anything in first_plugin
```

Its kinda a pain but writing libraries is not easy (wait till you use CMake with C/C++, you have to specify *every* ***single*** *file* in your source tree :D)

Comment: I think that the syntax for importing the whole plugin (while still simplifying the path) is rather `from first_plugin import *`, isn't it ? with your syntax I believe that you must still type `from plugins.first_plugin import ...` right ?

Comment: Crap your right, sorry im tired ill edit it to add that. Also if you want to use the `*` to import all from your library you should define a list called `__all__` with the module names to be auto imported with `*`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could elaborate on answers of this post: [How to import all submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365740/how-to-import-all-submodules)

For example with `pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__)` you'd have a list of modules. Then you could use `dir` on the loaded module and import the results (filtering elements starting with `__`

Comment: But still that would import only the submodules if I'm not mistaken, whereas I want to import the classes that are defined in the submodules.

Comment: If you use dir on the modules then you will have the names of the classes. I’m pretty sure that you can import them with their name. I can’t try it now but I’ll try tomorrow if you haven’t figured it out until then.