# Import submodules all at once

Tags: python, function, import, module, compiler-errors

I'm quite new at Python, but I'm experienced with other programming languages.

I have this line of code:

```
import module as m
```

If I try to access its functions:

```
m.spam.foo()
m.eggs.bar()
```

I get the following errors:

```
AttributeError: module 'module' has no attribute 'spam'
AttributeError: module 'module' has no attribute 'eggs'
```

---

On the other hand, if I write:

```
import module.spam, module.eggs
```

and then:

```
module.spam.foo()
module.eggs.bar()
```

It works properly.

---

Same if I write:

```
from module import spam, eggs
```

and:

```
spam.foo()
eggs.bar()
```

Works with no errors.

---

I prefer the first method since I don't have to manually `import` every single *submodule* before using it...

So, what's wrong with that method? Is there a workaround to make it work *(I do not like the `from module import *` approach since they can be confused with my global variables)*?

I searched everywhere inside the reference but could not find anything.

Comment: Importing all the modules at the beginning is the recommended technique in [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) — there are exceptions to the rule, of course.

Comment: Thanks... I didn't know about it! Anyway, it doesn't solve the fact that I have to manually import every single submodule

Comment: If your question is about submodules in a Python package, you can `import` things from the submodules in the package's `__init__.py` file. Normally this will require explicitly importing everything. There are however ways of doing that automatically (and I've answered other questions showed how to do it if you're interested).

Comment: @martineau is this file `__init__.py` automatically included in every third party libraries or should I create it manually?

Comment: Packages come with one because it's a big part of what makes them a package. I think you should look up "package" in the documentation (or some other Python resource). Also see my answer to [How to import members of all modules within a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426574/how-to-import-members-of-all-modules-within-a-package)

Comment: @martineau Importing `module.__init__`  I still get the error `AttributeError: module 'module' has no attribute 'spam'`... I cannot understand whether I'm doing something wrong, since `module.__init__` is actually imported with no errors.

Comment: You still don't understand how packages work — the `__init__.py` is imported automatically when you import the package or one of the submodules in it.

Comment: @martineau so the submodules should automatically be imported... Why do I get these errors?

Comment: No, submodules will not be automatically imported. The `__init__.py` is what tells Python that the folder it is in is a package. You can manually `import` stuff from the sub-modules in the `__init__.py` and they will be appear to be in _its_ name namespace instead of the submodule's. There are ways to make this importing of submodules happen automatically (by adding some code that looks for submodules a imports whatever is in them into the packages namespace). Afterwards, If you want everything, you can just do `from package import *`.

Comment: @martineau thank you... one last question. What if I want to import all the submodules and keep them inside the parent module? The problem with `from package import *` is that the submodules are saved inside their own namespaces. I'd like to access them from the main module (`module.egg.foo()` instead of `egg.foo()`)

Comment: Hard to tell from your example, but if you had an empty `__init__.py`, then you could `import` a module in the package via `from package import module`. Afterwards `module.egg.foo()` would be valid (assuming something named `egg` with a callable `foo` is defined in it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well this solves your problem, because this code is actually longer than the `from module import spam, eggs` method, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365740/how-to-import-all-submodules) might solve your problem. Basically, you would use an `__init__` function to load all submodules.

Comment: It doesn't, since my module is a third party library (`matplotlib`) so I think that editing it is not a good idea...

Comment: Sorry. Best I had.

Comment: @Foxel: If the third party package doesn't supply and `__iinit__.py`, you shouldn't try creating one. You could create your own **module** and import a bunch of things from other modules & packages into **it**, and then use `from my_module import *` and access to all of them. You can also explicitly state what should be included by `… import *` by defining a list  named `__all__` with their names in it in the module's code.

Comment: @martineau I tried importing it and the file actually exists, the problem is that I still get the same errors