# How can I use Python modules without having to explicitly import them?

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I am trying to make it possible to import modules for my program. In this code I've received all files but when I try to import the variables, it returns an error.

I don't want to hardcode the import in the code, I want to be able to add new python files without having to manually add them to the code. See the `loadCommandFiles()` function to see what I tried.

main file:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

def main():
    global main_entry
    main_entry = tk.Entry(font = ("Helvetica", 30, "bold"))
    main_entry.pack()
    main_entry.focus_set()
    main_entry.bind('<Return>', entry_parser)

def entry_parser(dontCare):
    entry_string = main_entry.get()

def loadCommandFiles():
    for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            if file.endswith("jarvis.py") == False:
                exec("import {}".format(file.replace(".py", "")))
                print(basicCommands.commands)
                
terminal = tk.Tk()
terminal.overrideredirect(True)

terminal.geometry("+{}+{}".format(int(terminal.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - terminal.winfo_reqwidth()/2), int(terminal.winfo_screenheight()/2 - terminal.winfo_reqheight()/2)))

loadCommandFiles()

main()

terminal.mainloop()
```

basicCommands.py

```
commands = ["schnitzel"]
```

error:

> NameError: name 'basicCommands' is not defined

Comment: You have to `import basicCommands` in the main file.

Comment: But you're not even importing `basicCommands`, why would you think that you could use variables in it without importing it? You mentioned that you're importing another file but there's no `import basicCommands`.

Comment: @Gary02127 yea, but I want to be able to add python files without hardcoding them in the main code.

Comment: @thekingoflorda then how do you want it to work? You want to just automatically have every .py file in the same directory be imported? That's possible to do with code but you didn't specify that all in your post.

Comment: @RandomDavis yup I did mean that. I've changed the text to better explain this.

Comment: Okay but there's already a lot of answered questions on how to do that. What's special about what you want? Does this answer your question? [How to import all submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365740/how-to-import-all-submodules)

Answer (score 0):

Start your main program with:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import basicCommands
```

If you want to import progammatically, try changing the line:

```
            exec("_import '{}'".format(file.replace(".py", "")))
```

to:

```
            __import__(file.replace(".py", ""))
```