# FastAPI import routers from separate file

Tags: python, fastapi, web-development-server

I am trying to import routers from a separate file instead of mentioning  `app.include_router()` for each router in the FastAPI app file. I want to avoid the include router statement for each router in the main file and would like to split it into another file. I would like to include the routers in a separate file. Is this possible?

Comment: There is nothing limiting you from having `from .main import app` in a `routes.py`, and then having `import .routes` at the end of `main.py` (i.e. importing a file that populates the routes in your app after defining your app). Would that work?

Answer (score 3):

**Sure, you can do that.**

### for static import (normal cases)

From your `app/routes/__init__.py`, you can try

```
import route1
import route2
import route3
__all__ = ['route1', 'route2', 'route3']
```

> You could even do without defining **all**, but things (pydoc, if
> nothing else) will work more cleanly if you define it, even if it's
> just a list of what you imported.

(for dynamic import and more over:
[How to import all submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365740/how-to-import-all-submodules/3365846#3365846))