# why doesn’t `from . import *` import all submodules?

Tags: python, module, python-import

I have a module `mymodule` with several submodules, let’s say

```
mymodule/
   __init__.py
   module1.py
   module2.py
   ...
```

For side-effects reasons, I need all those submodules to be run when `mymodule` is imported.

I tried adding the following to `__init__.py`

```py
from . import *
```

But that didn’t work (the submodules were not imported when `mymodule` was)

**I solved it** by using `pkgutil` as described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365740/how-to-import-all-submodules)

My question is the following :

### Why doesn’t `from . import *` work as one would expect?

(when `from . import module1` for examples works as expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) on `from module import *`

the command `from module import *` doesn’t actually import all names in the `module`, instead it imports all names listed in the `__all__` variable in the module.

And, citing the python doc

> If `__all__` is not defined, the statement from sound.effects import * does not import all submodules from the package `sound.effects` into the current namespace; it only ensures that the package `sound.effects` has been imported (possibly running any initialization code in `__init__.py`) and then imports whatever names are defined in the package. This includes any names defined (and submodules explicitly loaded) by `__init__.py`. It also includes any submodules of the package that were explicitly loaded by previous import statements.