# Import all functions from all submodules of a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have the following folder structure of python modules:

```
allFunctions
    ├─ import_all.py
    ├─ __init__.py
    ├─ funcSetA
    ├─ __init__.py
    │   ├─ funcA1.py
    │   └─ funcA2.py
    └─ funcSetB
        ├─ __init__.py
        ├─ funcB1.py
        ├─ funcB2.py
        └─ funcB3.py
```

I want to import all the functions to be useable as `funcA1()`, or at worst `allFunctions.funcA1()`, but explicitly not as `allFunctions.funcSetA.funcA1()`. I also want to import the functions using the script import_all.py,  not with the top level`__init__.py` (other levels are fine). I am not worried about namespace conflicts as the function names are very specific

I tried doing the following:

```
import allFunctions
from allFunctions import funcSetA as funcSetA
from funcSetA import funcA1
```

but obviously this doesn't work

I'm running python3.10

Comment: I think this might help (not sure though, for I read it very cursorily): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365740/how-to-import-all-submodules

Comment: @Swifty its along the same lines but its not quite what I want to do

Comment: first you have to import `funcA1` inside `allFunctions/__init__.py` to get it later as `from allFunctions import funcA1`. And if you want to import it as `from funcSetA import funcA1` then first you have to import `funcA1` inside `funcSetA/__init__.py`. And you have it in link in first comment as `import script` and `__all__ = ['script1', 'script2', 'script3']`

Comment: BTW: you have file `funcA1.py` but you would need also function `funcA1()` inside this file and import it as `from funcA1 import funcA1` (which means `from file funcA1.py import function funcA1()`). File `funcA1.py` can't be used as function `funcA1()`

Answer (score 0):

Many stack overflow pages later I compiled an answer. I absolutely cannot recommend anyone does this, I had very specific reasons for doing things this way - but it does work. This code goes in the top level `__init__.py` (it might be possible to make a loader script like I originally wanted, I stopped trying. All `__init__.py` files in any folder other than the top level is completely blank (again, very specific reasons...)

```
import pkgutil
#import the packages

__all__ = []
for loader, module_name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
    modNameSplit = module_name.split(".")[-1]
    __all__.append(modNameSplit)
    _module = loader.find_module(module_name).load_module(module_name)
    globals()[modNameSplit] = _module

    
    #if functions exist within the module, this imports them
    module_dict = _module.__dict__
    try:
        to_import = _module.__all__
    except AttributeError:
        to_import = [name for name in module_dict if not name.startswith('_')]
    globals().update({name: module_dict[name] for name in to_import})
```